# how count the number of elements with the same sign?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

How I can count the number of repetitive positive or negative elements in each row?

Suppose I have the following data:

```
ski      2020    2021      2022     2023       2024      2025
book      1.2     5.6       8.4      -2         -5         6
jar       4.2      -5        -8      2          4           6
kook       -4      -5.2      -2.3    -5.6        -7        8
```

The output is a list for each row that counts the number of similar signs. For example in the first row we have 3 positive elements and then 2 negative and again one positive. So the output is `[3,-2,1]`.
and for 2 other rows the output is as follows:

```
 jar   [1,-2,3]
 kook   [-5,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) using Python's `itertools.groupby` (`lambda x: (1, -1)[x<0]` is the sign function)

```
df.show()
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+                                    
# |   0|     1|     2|     3|     4|   5|   6|
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+
# | ski|2020.0|2021.0|2022.0|2023.0|2024|2025|
# |book|   1.2|   5.6|   8.4|  -2.0|  -5|   6|
# | jar|   4.2|  -5.0|  -8.0|   2.0|   4|   6|
# |kook|  -4.0|  -5.2|  -2.3|  -5.6|  -7|   8|
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array
from itertools import groupby
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType
 
def count_signs(l):
     return [(s*len(list(g))) for s, g in groupby(map(lambda x: (1, -1)[x<0], l))]

count_signs_udf = udf(count_signs, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df.withColumn('signs', count_signs_udf(array(df.columns[1:]))).show()
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+----------+
# |   0|     1|     2|     3|     4|   5|   6|     signs|
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+----------+
# | ski|2020.0|2021.0|2022.0|2023.0|2024|2025|       [6]|
# |book|   1.2|   5.6|   8.4|  -2.0|  -5|   6|[3, -2, 1]|
# | jar|   4.2|  -5.0|  -8.0|   2.0|   4|   6|[1, -2, 3]|
# |kook|  -4.0|  -5.2|  -2.3|  -5.6|  -7|   8|   [-5, 1]|
# +----+------+------+------+------+----+----+----------+
```